# Regex for validating a string with pre-specified special characters

Tags: regex, validation

I am looking for a regex to validate a string. I want to allow numbers, alpha characters, spaces and any of the following characters in any order:

```
+ - ( ) ,
```

I would be grateful if someone could help. thanks

Comment: And what do you want from us? To wish you good luck?

Comment: This is (almost) the most basic regex that is possible to write.  You should learn regular expressions.

Comment: joren, I am sorry I have updated my post to make it sensible. I am very bad at Regex

Comment: What about accented characters (à, ä, etc.)? What language are you using to validate the string?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker. I am using Java and I only want to allow the special characters I listed no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 +(),-]+$/
```

**EDIT**: Now accepts spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex was:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9+\\s(),-]+$
```

many thanks to Slaks who almost responded with the correct one except not accomodating the whitespaces

Comment: Caveat: `\s` also matches tab, carriage return, form feed and newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9+(), -]+$/
```