# Python regex exact match for three characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a method that takes a string input and checks if the string is valid for the following criteria:

- The string must be at least one character long
- The string can only contain the following characters: `.`, , `A`, or `B`
- An exception is raised if the string is invalid

Valid string examples are:

```
AB..AA...
BB
.
A
..A.....
etc.
```

There is no length limit.

My initial attempt does not work:

```
import re

def validate(string):
    re.search(r"[AB.]+", string)
```

Comment: Is that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523133/regex-for-validating-a-string-with-pre-specified-special-characters

Comment: Just to be clear, `etc.` should not be in the list of acceptable examples, right?

Comment: Robb Mop gave the good answer, for your information you have two main issues: 1) the dot `.`has special meaning in a regex and thus must be escaped (prefixed by a backslash), and 2) since you want to check that the whole string matches the conditions (and not simply a part of it), you want to match the string from the start anchor `^` toi the end `$`. And I guess `R` and `L` were supposed to be `A` and `B` in this example?

Comment: The `[AB.]+` pattern is fine. Just use `re.fullmatch`, not `re.search`, to match the whole input.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
^[\.AB]+$
```

As seen [here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/A3omAe/1)

## Explanation:

`^` and `$` stand for the start and end of a line respectively.

`[\.AB]+` means one or more characters that are either a period, A or B.